# How to add Transactions with a DataSet created using the Add Connection Wizard?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, transactions

I have a DataSet that I have added to my project where I can Insert and Add records using the Add Query function in Visual Studio 2010, however I want to add transactions to this, I have found a few examples but cannot seem to find one that works with these.

I know I need to use the SQLClient.SQLTransaction Class somehow. I used the Add New Data Source Wizard and added the Tables/View/Functions I need, I just need an example using this process such as How to get the DataConnection my DataSet has used. Assuming all options have been set in the wizard and I am only using the pre-defined adapters and options asked for in this wizard, how to I add the Transaction logic to my Database.

For example I have a DataSet called ProductDataSet with the XSD created for this, I have then added my Stock table as a Datasource and Added an AddStock method with a wizard, this also if a new item calls an AddItem method, if either of these fails I want to rollback the AddItem and AddStock in this case.

Comment: You might also want to look at the `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` class.

Comment: Thanks had looked at that too, but was not sure it was used for this purpose, might have missed it however so thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: If there are any examples of adding transactions when the wizard has been used for creating a Data Source and Data Set, then please link to them or mention them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, I have a dataset called "dsMain" and a few direct queries in a "QueriesTableAdapter".  I extend the partial class for the TableAdapter with a function that will create a transaction based on the first (0) connection and then apply it to every connection in the table adapter.

```
Namespace dsMainTableAdapters
    Partial Public Class QueriesTableAdapter
        Public Function CreateTransaction() As Data.IDbTransaction   
            Dim oConnection = Me.CommandCollection(0).Connection
            oConnection.Open()

            Dim oTrans = oConnection.BeginTransaction()

            For Each cmd In Me.CommandCollection
                cmd.Connection = oConnection
                cmd.Transaction = oTrans
            Next

            Return oTrans
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

You begin the transaction by calling the new function

```
Dim qa As New dsMainTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
Dim oTrans = qa.CreateTransaction()
```

Then you can call TableAdapter queries within your transaction

```
qa.Query1
qa.Query2
```

When you are done with your queries you commit the transaction

```
oTrans.Commit()
```

You can do the same thing for any TableAdapter that was created for your datasets.
If you have multiple TableAdapters that need to use the same transaction, then in addition to a "CreateTransaction" you should make a "SetTransaction" and have the Transaction be a parameter.

Comment: Thanks looks interesting, cannot try it for now, but this looks like what I need - will mark as answer if I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for your answer carter, it helped me very much!

but iam not able to handle the part with the parameters

> You can do the same thing for any TableAdapter that was created for your datasets. If you have multiple TableAdapters that need to use the same transaction, then in addition to a "CreateTransaction" you should make a "SetTransaction" and have the Transaction be a parameter.

so iam able to handle 1 transactions with 1 tableadapter, but not 1 transaction with 2 tableadapters:

iam doing this for a school project, and i really need your help!!
here is the code to add a new material and a historical price to it(a changing price, like by fuel; iam saving it in an related table to material in the database):

```
Namespace DataSetTableAdapters
Partial Public Class MaterialPriceTableAdapter
Public Function SetTransaction() As Data.IDbTransaction

        Dim oConnection = Me.CommandCollection(0).Connection
        oConnection.Open()

        Dim oTrans = oConnection.BeginTransaction()

        For Each cmd In Me.CommandCollection
            cmd.Connection = oConnection
            cmd.Transaction = oTrans
        Next

        Return oTrans
    End Function
End Class

Partial Public Class MaterialTableAdapter

    Public Function CreateTransaction(ByVal MaterialPrice As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcTransaction) As Data.IDbTransaction

        Dim oConnection = Me.CommandCollection(0).Connection
        oConnection.Open()

        Dim oTrans = oConnection.BeginTransaction()

        For Each cmd In Me.CommandCollection
            cmd.Connection = oConnection
            cmd.Transaction = oTrans
        Next

        Return oTrans
    End Function
End Namspace
```

`

and now the code in the form the form:

```
Public Class AddMaterial
Dim material As New DataSetBATableAdapters.MaterialTableAdapter
Dim materialprice As New DataSetBATableAdapters.MaterialPriceTableAdapter
Dim oTrans = material.CreateTransaction(materialprice.SetTransaction())

Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    Try
        material.InsertQuery(NameTextBox.Text, UnitComboBox.SelectedValue)
        materialprice.InsertQuery(Date_BeginDateTimePicker.Value, PriceTextBox.Text, Date_EndDateTimePicker.Value, Me.LkwTableAdapter.ScalarQuery())
        oTrans.Commit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        oTrans.Rollback()
        MsgBox("Error by Insert")
    End Try
    Me.Close
End Sub
End Class
```

if i save a new record the materialprice.insertquery isnt commited by otrans.commit. what am i doing wrong? if you have an idea what it is, please tell me

thanks,
Xeras

Comment: My solution for this issue where you need to pass the Transaction object was to use a single table adapter with the inserts statements on this as I could not get the transaction object to persist correctly, hopefully there is a way to get a single transaction object to persist between TableAdapters, but I tried a few things and they did not work for me, but they may for you.

Comment: haha this works for me :)), i am writing both insert statements from the same tableadapter, never thought of that, very nice thanks a looooot!!!

Comment: Glad it helped! I had not considered this at first either, it was only because I could get it to work with the one adapter but not two that it occured to me to put all the inserts in the first adapter, and this worked even though they were for different tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but this is how I imaging the CreateTransaction/SetTransaction combo should be written (with your OdbcTransaction object).

```
Public Function CreateTransaction() As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcTransaction
    Dim oConnection = Me.CommandCollection(0).Connection
    oConnection.Open()

    Dim oTrans = oConnection.BeginTransaction()

    SetTransaction(oTrans)

    Return oTrans
End Function


Public Sub SetTransaction(ByVal oTrans As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcTransaction)
    For Each cmd In Me.CommandCollection
        cmd.Connection = oTrans.Connection
        cmd.Transaction = oTrans
    Next
End Sub
```